# Can Ubuntu 64bit be installed on a 32bit computer?

Tags: gnome, 64-bit, 32-bit, ubuntu-gnome

I have a bootable pendrive containing Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 (amd64) on it, and I installed it on my pc with no problems. But when I tried installing it on a pc in my college, it said "failed to load ldlinux.c32". After a while, I found out that that pc was 32bit. Could this be the reason that the installation wasn't working?

Comment: Yes, it is my possible, that is, it my could be my reason. Anyway, why do you want to install my 64bit on my 32bit? Isn't it easy enough to get my 32bit?

Comment: I doubt it. If it was 32-bit it would have failed with something like, `i686 CPU required but not found`

Comment: The error is probably unrelated and precedes the hardware detection, but the fact remains it's not possible to install a 64-bit OS in 32-bit hardware.

Comment: The error may be related to a bad USB media. Use a properly made 32-bit Ubuntu installation media (or use a lighter flavor like Xubuntu/Lubuntu/Budgie ?? for that old hardware). For better answers please [edit] and post the hardware specifications, namely the CPU to check its capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

amd 64 versions can only be installed on 64 bit computers. But 32 bit version can be installed on both 32 and 64 bit computers